# How do I train a DaskLGBMClassifier using dask-cudf dataframe

Tags: dask, lightgbm, dask-dataframe, cudf

I have a dask_cudf dataframe on which I have applied train test split to obtain the respective train, test data.

I am using DaskLGBMClassifier to train a classifier model & I can use dask dataframe to fit this model without issues

```
model.fit(X_train_dask.values, y_train_dask.values)
```

However error occurs when I do this

```
model.fit(X_train_dask_cudf.values, y_train_dask_cudf.values)
```

Error is

```
You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to 
determine the type of output that that function returns. 

To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
The docstring of the Dask function you ran should have more information.

Original error is below:
------------------------
RuntimeError('CuPy failed to load libnvrtc.so.12: OSError: libnvrtc.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

Also tried fitting using the dask_cudf dataframe without converting to arrays. But got below error

```
TypeError: Data must be one of: numpy arrays, pandas dataframes, sparse matrices (from scipy). Got DataFrame.
```

Does someone know what could be going wrong here ?.

Comment: Can you share the CUDA version you have installed, and how it was installed (conda, apt, etc)? It seems like CuPy is failing to find NVRTC from CUDA 12.

Comment: @BradleyDice- CUDA version installed is cuda_11.8.r11.8

Comment: My guess is that you need to match the CUDA major versions of the software you have installed. CuPy can't find `libnvrtc.so.12` because that is part of CUDA 12 but you have CUDA 11.